# A palavra “estoque” faz parte do português europeu?

Tags: português-europeu

A palavra portuguesa “[estoque](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/estoque)” faz parte do português europeu, em Portugal, ou só a palavra inglesa “[stock](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/stock)”?

Citações:

> **Gestão de stocks** <sup>([pt](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portugu%C3%AAs_europeu))</sup> ou **Administração de estoques** <sup>([pt-BR](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portugu%C3%AAs_brasileiro))</sup> [...]

Fonte: artigo “[Gestão de stocks](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gest%C3%A3o_de_stocks)”.

> Em [administração](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Administra%C3%A7%C3%A3o), **estoque** ([português brasileiro](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portugu%C3%AAs_brasileiro)) ou **existências/stock** ([português europeu](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portugu%C3%AAs_europeu)), [...]

Fonte: artigo “[Estoque](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estoque)”.

> **Portugal** (norma luso-afro-asiática)
>   **stock** (em itálico ou entre aspas) e **estoque**

Fonte: blogue “[.stock ou estoque?](http://portuguesemforma.blogspot.com/2012/11/stock-ou-estoque.html)”.

Comment: Em Portugal ensinava-se a usar existências/stock mesmo depois do AO. É o termo corrente na gestão.

Comment: https://dicionario.priberam.org/estoque Não conhece o Priberam??

Answer (score 1):

Não. Em português europeu, usa-se o termo inglês, "stock", ou o português, "inventário". "Estoque" existe em português europeu, mas não com esse significado: [Dicionário Priberam: «estoque»](https://dicionario.priberam.org/estoque).

Aliás, por norma, estrangeirismos "traduzidos" para português, tais como:

- "nocaute" (*knock-out*);
- "estresse" *(stress)*;
- "esporte" (*sport*)

são de origem brasileira. Em português europeu, não existe um grande hábito de "aportuguesar" palavras inglesas.

Answer (score 0):

A palavra Portuguesa "estoque" refere se a "espada reta e pontiaguda, com folha triangular ou quadrangular e fio não cortante [Somente a ponta causa ferimentos.]."
Não existe Português Europeu nem Brasileiro, Existe somente Português, a língua é apenas uma. Estrangeirismos criados/usados quer pelo povo Português, quer pelo povo Brasileiro são exactamente isso apenas, estrangeirismos. Não fazem parte da língua Portuguesa e quando utilizados num contexto formal e escrito deverão ser identificados entre áspas e itálico.
O povo português por norma mantém a palavra estrangeira original devido à sua cultura mais conservadora e regrada, enquanto que o povo Brasileiro tem tendência a fazer adaptações, uma vez que a nível fonético a língua portuguesa FALADA no Brasil é muito direcionada para vogais abertas. Isto está directamente relacionado com a cultura Brasileira, mais liberal e despreocupada no que diz respeito a regras.
Como referido no comentário no comentário anterior, a palavra portuguesa correspondente ao estrangeirismo "estoque", é inventario ou existências.

Comment: André, bem-vindo! Desculpa, mas quem decide se se escreve "estoque" no Brasil não é o brasileiro (b minúsculo). Se as autoridades, como dicionários, dissessem que "estoque" fosse errado, vários não escreveriam "estoque", apenas "stock". Outra coisa: "estoque" não deve se escrever em itálico porque é um aportuguesamento do inglês "stock". O português na Europa também faz isso, como "piza" ou "golo", mas no Brasil escrevemos "pizza" e "gol", em sua maioria. Isso sem falar de palavras francesas, italianas e latinas. Não existem regras contra aportuguesar uma palavra, não é errado fazer isso.

Comment: André, porém, estás bem-vindo a contra-argumentar-me. Por sinal, neste site, recomenda-se usar referências nas respostas.